# How to pass Arguments to this signature?

Tags: javascript

I see a JavaScript Signature like:

```
attachMetadataFailed(oData?, fnFunction, oListener?)
```

now I know, that the first and the last parameter are optional. But the mandatory parameter is in the middle.

How can I call the function, if I dont want to set the optional parameters?
I think when I will use `attachMetadataFailed(function() {...})` that I will access just the first parameter which is optional or not?

Comment: Can't you just try and see? ) Actually, it depends on that function's implementation - one can check arguments `typeof`, for example.

Comment: I guess it's designed like e.g. `$.post` and looks at the argument type. That is, `foo(function()...)` should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't provide a way to call a function while providing argument 2 but not argument 1.

You can either:

## Explicitly pass an undefined value

```
foo(undefined, 123);
```

## Have the function detect the object type

```
function foo (obj, func) {
    if (typeof func === "undefined" && typeof obj === "function") {
        func = obj;
        obj = undefined;
    }
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a thrid-party function and you are reading the documentation for it. If the documentation is true, then:

- If you pass one parameter, it will be bound to `fnFunction`.
- If you pass two, the first one will be bound to `oData` and the second one to `fnFunction`.
- If you pass three, the first one will be bound to `oData`, the second one to `fnFunction`, and the third one to `oListener`.

So `attachMetadataFailed(myfn)` will behave the same as `attachMetadataFailed(undefined, myfn)`.

Yes, JavaScript can manage that. See Quentin answer for how you can do it with your own functions.